# Wave function characteristics

Tags: quantum-chemistry

In a book, I read that the wave function of a system should not become infinite in a finite region and also should vanish at infinity.
For the first part I think that if wave function is infinite in finite region the normalization constant becomes zero due to which wave function vanishes. 
But I am not able to find the reason behind the vanishing of wave function at infinity.
Please clarify this doubt.

Comment: It's a boundary condition.

Comment: because the wavefunction integral must evaluate to 1, a finite value at infinity cannot sum to 1